# Need to get value from dynamically named selectbox

Tags: c#

I have a datalist that has this inside:

```
<select id="ddl<%# Eval("ID") %>" name="ddl<%# Eval("ID") %>">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
                <option>9</option>
                <option>10</option>
                <option>11</option>
                <option>12</option>
                <option>13</option>
                <option>14</option>
                <option>15</option>
                <option>16</option>
                <option>17</option>
                <option>18</option>
                <option>19</option>
                <option>20</option>
            </select>
```

Because of the dynamically named input, I can't add the runat server tag.

On my code behind of a button event, I am trying to get the option text; I'm using:

```
string itemquantity = Request.Form.GetValues("ddl" + itemid).ToString();
```

That returns object reference not found.

Any ideas how to handle this?

Comment: maybe I could loop through all the select boxes and come up with a list of names and values? still have no idea, there has to be an easier way, I dont even know how to do that without them being .net controls.

Answer (score 0):

Use OnItemDataBound event of DataList where you can use FindControl method to find this Select..

But you should add runat="server" tag or use DropdownList control.

Comment: i can't use a runat server tag because it doesn't have a solid id, and can't use databound event because its coming from a code behind button event.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden field.
Using jquery, for each change on any of dropdownlist create an event which read values from each dropdownlist and store it in hiddenfield as list, eg. comma separated.